# What is the proper way to call javascript functions from within a rails view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm really new to rails and the asset pipeline has been tripping me up for a bit. From what I understand, all javascript files in the `assets/javascripts` directory are compiled into one singular js file called `application.js` that contains all the functions in all the js files in the directory. My first question is, what happens if there's a naming conflict and two files in `assets/javascripts` have functions with the same name?

Secondly, what's the best practice for calling these functions? For example, in my view, I have a modal with a form that when submitted, I want the modal to disappear. I can do this

app/views/my_directory/index.html.haml

```
= form_with url: my_directory_path, class: "form", :html => { onsubmit: "hideModal()" },  method: :get do |form|
            = form.date_select
            %br
            %button.btn.btn-primary{type: "submit", class: "submitBtn"} Submit
```

app/assets/javascripts/modal.js

```
function hideModal() {
    $modal.modal('hide');
}
```

And that works fine. But from what I've read, it's not good practice to call javascript from within your rails view. So my second question is, what IS good practice? I've tried to delete the `onsubmit` option from my form and do this instead

modal.js

```
$('.form').submit(function() {
$modal.modal('hide');
})
```

but this doesn't work. I assume because it can't find the form, because there's no script tag with the javascript file within the `index.html.haml`. My guess is I'm misunderstanding how the asset pipeline works and how it "links" your javascript files and views together.

I'm working with Rails 5.2.

Comment: Before diving into this question, you're probably going to want to identify your version of Rails in order to figure out whether you can only do things the old way (asset pipeline) or the new way ([webpacker](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html) in Rails 5 and 6). While you can still use the asset pipeline with the latest major versions of Rails, you may want to avail yourself of some of the advantages conferred by webpacker.

Comment: I am on Rails 5.2

Comment: If the JS is rendered before DOM ready there won't be a `.form` yet; attaching event handlers needs to be done on DOM ready.